# JDeveloper can't find method for f:view's beforePhase

Tags: java, jsf, jdeveloper

Using JDev 11.1.1.3.0. I select the `f:view` tag in the source, go to the method expression builder for `beforePhase` and select my method from the backing bean (which has the correct signature, otherwise it wouldn't even show up in the method expression builder). Still, JDev gives me the error "Reference 'method_name' not found".

Seems to be the same problem as mentioned in [this thread on the Oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1131554).

Any ideas? Is this a JDev bug or am I screwing up the definition of the phase listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
beforePhase="#{bean.method}"
```

Is fine. If the method exists in the bean, it's a jdev bug. Btw, for jsf 1.2 with facelets it is `beforePhaseListener`

Comment: I have `beforePhase="#{backing_student.updateCurrentLogin}"`, which gives the error. beforePhaseListener="#{backing_student.updateCurrentLogin}" just says "attribute beforePhaseListener not defined on element f:view".

Comment: Awesome. So what, do I have to write a phase listener class now?

Comment: just ignore the error. It should work despite it (just to repeat - if using jsf 1.2 with facelets, use `beforePhaseListener`, even if an error is shown)